# JavaScript reduce ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reduce, ternary

This is silly, but I'm having hard time understanding how these two statements outputs different results.

```
'theyyyyy wheels on q bus'.split(' ').reduce((shortest, w) => {
   return  w.length < shortest.length ? shortest = w : shortest;
 }) // 'q'

'theyyyyy wheels on q bus'.split(' ').reduce((shortest, w) => {
  return shortest.length > w.lenght ? shortest = w : shortest;
}) // 'theyyyyy'
```

Comment: you have a typo: `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: Also, assigning to `shortest = w` won't d anything. Just return `w` and `reduce` will take care of the assigning behind the scenes.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, you have `w.lenght` which is undefined. Change to `w.length`.